# S3 kafka connect status api is always return not found status code

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I used S3 kafka connect.
S3 connect works fine, but the api to detect the status of the connection always returns 404.

For example

```
GET /connectors
GET /connectors/{name}
POST /connectors
PUT /connectors/{name}
DELETE /connectors/{name}
```

All of these apis are functioning normally.

but API for determining the current state of connect and tasks.

```
GET /connectors/{name}/status
GET /connectors/{name}/tasks/{taskId}
```

is not operating normally. We are always returning 404.

Is there an option to activate that api? Or what is wrong with it?

Comment: Connect registration was conducted through api.

Comment: If there is more than one worker in the cluster, make sure that their advertised listeners settings are resolvable to each other

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was that status.storage.replication.factor was set to 1

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below rather than leave it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was that status.storage.replication.factor was set to 1

Comment: did you change it to -1 ?